# How do I use pdfliteral with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

I am learning tikz and how to draw stuff in it. One of the examples I have is to draw the periodic table (since I need to be able to draw a nice one and modify it to my needs). The piece of code that is giving me problems is:

```
\ifpdf
  % Couldn't find a nicer way of doing an outline font with TikZ
  % other than using pdfliteral 1 Tr

  \pdfliteral direct {0.5 w 1 Tr}{#1}%
  \pdfliteral direct {1 w 0 Tr}%
\else
   %pstricks can do this with \pscharpath from pstricks

  \pscharpath[shadow=false,
    fillstyle=solid,
    fillcolor=white,
    linestyle=solid,
    linecolor=black,
    linewidth=.2pt]{#1} 
\fi
```

This code compiles well and produces text that has a black outline and is filled in white (when combined with all the other commands). What I want is to change the color of the fill. I cannot find information on `\pdfliteral` and the code given makes no sense to me. The `pstricks` part is easy. Can someone please explain this very strange way of writing commands and what each part of the command means?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [`contour`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/contour) package, which is also topic of the following question: [How can I put a coloured outline around fraction lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/how-can-i-put-a-coloured-outline-around-fraction-lines). The package works fine with TikZ nodes.

Comment: I think you asking the wrong way: Either ask "How to do draw character outlines in TikZ" or "How to change the color in \pdfliteral". The `\pdfliteral` adds plain PDF code into the PDF. It has nothing to do with TikZ.

Comment: A very fine document is `pdf-trans.tex` . You can find it here : http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/pdf-trans. It's a set of macros for various transformations of TeX boxes. And as Martin wrote : `\pdfliteral` has nothing to do with TikZ. But it's possible to mix TikZ and `\pdfliteral`. More precisely, TikZ uses a lot of `\pdfliteral` inside the drivers.

Comment: We've not had any clarification on this question, and it's clear that there is confusion about the relationship between Tikz and PDF output. This is therefore 'not a real question'.