# Use node text as argument for a macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a TikZ style that adds a thick outline to the node text using the `\contour{<colour>}{<text>}` macro from the `contour` package (as in the answer to the question [TikZ: halo around text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/18473#18473)), i.e. I want to define a style `halo` so that

```
\node [halo] {Text};
```

is equivalent to

```
\node {\contour{red}{Text}};
```

My problem is that I cannot tell TikZ to use the node text as an argument for a macro.

The `font` option only works with switches like `\itshape` (as opposed to `\textit{}`, which requires the text to be italicised to be provided in the argument).

There are two keys `execute at begin node={<code>}` and `execute at end node={<code>}` that can be used to call code at the beginning and end of the node, but I can't split the `\contour` command up using `execute at begin node={\contour{red{}` and `execute at end node={}}` because the brackets don't match. Replacing `{` with `\bgroup` and `}` with `\egroup` fails with `Missing } inserted`.

Here's am MWE to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.2pt}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\contour{red}{Text}};
%    \node [font=\contour{red}{}] {Text}; % Doesn't change the text
%    \node [execute at begin node={\contour{red}{},execute at end node={}}] {Text};  % Fails with ``Runaway argument?''
%    \node [execute at begin node={\contour{red}\bgroup},execute at end node={\egroup}] {Text};  % Fails with ``Missing } inserted''
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't you split the command using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`?  If you look at the code for the key `matrix of nodes` in the `matrix` library then that's what it does (according to the manual - I didn't look at the code).

Comment: @Andrew: Good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work in this case. Expansion stuff, probably (that's my catch-all excuse TeX problems that I don't understand)...

Comment: Does looking at the code of the contour package help? Maybe internally it is defined in a way that would allow you to split it in the right way?

Comment: The node content is actually not an argument of `\node` but typeset as a box. Also with "function" you mean "macro", right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After looking at the source code of `contour` (at least at the `pdftex` driver part) I figured that it typesets the text twice, once for the contour and once normally. The content must be short (i.e. not `\long`) and is processed in *restricted horizontal* mode. The issue is that TikZ processes the node content as box, not as macro argument. This is normally very good because it allows verbatim content etc. in the node, but doesn't allow direct access to the un-typeset content required for `\contour` and other macros.

Note that `\contour` partly works with boxed content if you use `\unhbox`. The issue is just that you need it twice and can't change the color! So either both have the same color which makes the contour not very useful or you only have  contour *without* the real text. I patched the `contour` source code (for `pdftex` only) to get you there:

```
% (uncomment the `%` lines to enable typesetting of the real text, but in the same color than the contour)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.1pt}

\makeatletter
\def\tikzcontour#1{%
    \begingroup
    \color{#1}%
    %\def\contourcolor{#1}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}%
}
% Mostly taken from `\@contour@outline` from `contour`s `pdftex.cnt` driver file:
% Work with pdftex only
\def\endtikzcontour{%
    \end{lrbox}%
    %\setbox0=\hbox{\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \begingroup
    \setlength\con@length{\con@base@length}%
    \setlength\con@length{2\con@length}%
    \setlength\con@length{0.99626400996\con@length}%
    %\color{\contourcolor}%
    \con@coloroff
    \pdfliteral{%
      q
      1 j
      1 J
      1 Tr
      \strip@pt\con@length\space w
    }%
    %\rlap
    \mbox% change back to `\rlap` when "real" text is drawn
    {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
    \pdfliteral{%
      Q
    }%
    \endgroup
    %\unhbox0
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [execute at begin node={\tikzcontour{red}},execute at end node={\endtikzcontour}] {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image: Result]

---

However it is possible to collect the content of the TikZ node with the same technique my `collcell` package uses to collect the content of a `tabular` cell, i.e. to skip the internal code header and read it token by token until the end is reached.

Here some proof-of-concept quick&dirty solution which reuses code from `collcell`. Do not use `\collectcell` with tables in the same file. I will write a dedicated, more stable solution when I find the time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.05em}
\usepackage{collcell}

\makeatletter

\def\collect@cell@look@{%
  \cc@case
    \@sptoken{%
      \edef\collect@cell@spaces{\collect@cell@spaces\space}%
      \collect@cell@eatspace
    }%
    \bgroup{\collect@cell@group}%
    \egroup{\afterassignment\collect@cell@end\let\@let@token=}%
    %\egroup{\collect@cell@end}%
    \default{\collect@cell@arg}%
  \endcc@case
}

\def\tikzcontour#1#2{\@tikzcontour{#1}#2\@endtikzcontour}
\def\@tikzcontour#1#2\ignorespaces#3\@endtikzcontour{%
          \bgroup%
            \ifx\tikz@textcolor\pgfutil@empty%
            \else%
              \pgfutil@colorlet{.}{\tikz@textcolor}%
            \fi%
            \pgfsetcolor{.}%
            \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\pgfutil@voidb@x%
            \tikz@uninstallcommands%
            \tikz@halign@check%
            \contour{#1}{\ignorespaces #3\unskip}%
            \egroup
            \tikz@fig@collectresetcolor%
        }
\let\collcell@afteruser=\empty
\makeatother

\tikzset{contour/.style={execute at begin node={\collectcell{\tikzcontour{#1}}\ignorespaces}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw,green,contour=red,circle] {Text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Wow, that looks very promising! One small issue: As it is now, this approach causes TikZ to lose track of the width (interestingly not of the height) of the text, adding `draw` will result in a rectangle of `minimum width`, but with correct height.

Comment: @Jake: I fixed that (was `\rlap` vs. `\mbox`) and also added a better solution.

Comment: Did you find time yet?

Comment: @cfr: sorry, not so far. I'm keeping very busy at work.