# Contour around multi-line tikz text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to produce a text inside a node which has a contour. Problem is: when using contour, text width seems to be ignored, so I can not use auto multi-line text.

I discovered contours in [tikz halo around text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/), and I can use it correctly as in:

```
\draw (0, 0) node {\contour{white}{A very long title that we mean to split on multiple lines}};
```

but when adding `text width` it is not multi-lined:

```
\draw (0, 0) node[text width=5cm] {\contour{white}{A very long title that we mean to split on multiple lines}};
```

And without contour it works correctly:

```
\draw (0, 0) node[text width=5cm] {A very long title that we mean to split on multiple lines};
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently `contour` puts everything in a box. Just try this, out of TikZ picture. `\contour{red}{A very long text that hopefully breaks at the end of the this line otherwise I need to write more stuff}`. So I think, the pragmatic approach is to break manually.

Comment: Same problem with `shadowtext` package. Very annoying. It seems there is no way of getting wrapping contour or shaded multiline text inside a TikZ node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Judging from the output of the [`pdfrender` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108875/16595), it seems that it does the same as the following TikZ code (which is coded as the opposite of optimal) *and* as the `contour` package.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{
    text shadow/.code args={[#1]#2at#3(#4)#5}{
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/.cd,#1}%
        \foreach \angle in {0,5,...,359}{
                \node[#1,text=white] at ([shift={(\angle:.5pt)}] #4){#5};
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray, step=.5mm] (-1.6,-1) rectangle (1.6,1);
    \node[
        text shadow={[align=center,text width=3cm] at (0,0) {A very long title that we mean to split on multiple lines \ldots}}]
                                      at (0,0) {A very long title that we mean to split on multiple lines \ldots};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]