# Blurred Chapter Title

Tags: fonts, sectioning, chapters

How can I create a blurred Chapter title such as this?

[image]

Comment: Related: [Blur the text so it's not readable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36552)

Answer (score 9):

One possibility; the idea is to use several copies of the string with different opacity and offsets (basically, a modification of the idea used in the answer to [Blur the text so it's not readable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36552/3954)).

First, a TikZ-free solution with the text and four offset copies:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{37}{48}\sffamily\filleft}
  {{\color{gray!15}\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}\hspace*{3.5pt}%
    \llap{\color{gray!15}\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}\hspace*{-1.75pt}%
    \llap{\color{gray!15}%
      \raisebox{1.75pt}[0pt][0pt]{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}}%
    \llap{\color{gray!15}%
      \raisebox{-1.75pt}[0pt][0pt]{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}}%
    \llap{\color{gray!40}%
      \chaptertitlename~\thechapter}}
  {20pt}{\huge\color{blue!50!black}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a solution using TikZ with the text and eight offset copies:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{37}{48}\sffamily\filleft}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[
    baseline,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,align=right},
    transparency group]
  \foreach \c in {0,...,7}  
    \node[shift={(45*\c:1.65pt)},opacity=0.03] {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter};
  \node[opacity=0.13] {\chaptertitlename~\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
  {20pt}{\huge\color{blue!50!black}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Test Chapter Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\foreach` loop (thanks to **Tom Bombadil** for this suggestion) allows to easily control the number and placement of offset copies.

I used the `titlesec` package interface, but this can be done directly, without using packages, by redefining the `\@makechapterhead` command (in `report` or `book`), or the command in charge of typeseting the chapter headings in any other document class.

Comment: You could also use a `foreach` loop for that: `\foreach \c in {0,...,3}` together with `\node[shift={(90*\c:1.5pt)}]`. This would make it easier to modify the number of copys and distances.

Comment: @TomBombadil that's a great suggestion! I'll incorporate it to my answer in some minutes. Thanks!

Comment: @TomBombadil I did something similar here: [Contour around multi-line tikz text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104211)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Hehe, I also thought of this as I once did it that way. I was always changing the number of loops, as few looked too bad and many took too long ;)

Comment: @TomBombadil True, but in this case, one could use TikZ’ `external` library, set the next file name to something dependent of the `chapter` counter so that even if one changes the order of chapters the process is only done once for every integer (unless you change fonts or the actual process).