# Scary Font Echo Effect

Tags: fonts, backgrounds, shadows

I'm trying to reproduce a strange font effect that is normally seen in horror movie trailers. In the trailers, a word will usually be flashed on screen, with 'echos' or 'shadows' of the word around it.

I failed utterly to find an example, but I rigged up an image that looks something like the effect:
[image]

In some renditions, the shadows overlap the word, in others the shadows don't touch the word; I am not particular.

My question is: How would you achieve this effect on a few words or part of a sentence using LaTeX?

For bonus points: Can the shadow effect be achieved and still leave the surrounding words readable?

[EDIT]For further clarification: I did specify 'LaTeX', but any flavor of tex is A-OK in my book.

Comment: See also [Blur the text so it's not readable](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36552) and for chapters [Blurred Chapter Title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118396).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This solution, using nested stack insets, still has vertical height/depth to the overlay.  The relative placement of the insets is controlled by the length parameters (2nd and 4th arguments of `\stackinset` are (x,y) offsets).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\MyText{not scary}
\newcommand\mytext[1][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\MyText}}
This is 
\stackinset{c}{2ex}{c}{1.4ex}{\mytext[red!90]}{%
\stackinset{c}{-3ex}{c}{3.2ex}{\mytext[black!25]}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1ex}{c}{-1.7ex}{\mytext[black!40]}{%
\mytext%
}}}
text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the cost of an additional argument, the echos can be scaled, as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\def\MyText{not scary}
\newcommand\mytext[2][black]{\scalebox{#2}{\textcolor{#1}{\MyText}}}
This is 
\stackinset{c}{2ex}{c}{1.4ex}{\mytext[red!90]{.8}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-3ex}{c}{3.2ex}{\mytext[black!25]{.7}}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1ex}{c}{-1.7ex}{\mytext[black!40]{1.1}}{%
\mytext{1}%
}}}
text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the vertical extent eliminated, so as to run into vertically adjacent text, a `\smash` takes care of that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\def\MyText{not scary}
\newcommand\mytext[1][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\MyText}}
\lipsum[1]
This is 
\smash{%
\stackinset{c}{2ex}{c}{1.4ex}{\mytext[red!90]}{%
\stackinset{c}{-3ex}{c}{3.2ex}{\mytext[black!25]}{%
\stackinset{c}{-1ex}{c}{-1.7ex}{\mytext[black!40]}{%
\mytext%
}}}}
text.
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In ZothiqueDemo font:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is just for demonstration purposes. That is, it is not intended to actually look like something you might use but rather to indicate how to achieve some effects which you might find useful in creating something which you would like to use. I thought I would play around with [shadowtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/shadowtext) and use the excuse to install the [emerald fonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/emerald). The 'scary' text is in various fonts from that collection: IntimacyDeux, Teenspirit, Webster, Skeetch, TallPaul and Pookie. `rotating` is used to rotate one sample without taking up space. `xcolor` is used so that the shadows' colours can be mixed on the spot.

[image: Font effects]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{emerald,texnames,rotating,xcolor,shadowtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\noindent\Huge This is some fairly mundane, absolutely non-terrifying text which could not be less scary if it tried. Gentle as a lamb and good as gold.
\shadowoffsetx{3pt}%
\shadowoffsety{5pt}%
\shadowtext{%
  \shadowoffsetx{-5pt}%
  \shadowoffsety{-3pt}%
  \shadowtext{%
    \shadowoffsetx{15pt}%
    \shadowoffsety{-12pt}%
    \shadowtext{%
      \Huge\ECFIntimacyDeux SCARY}}}
What in \shadowtext{\TeX}'s name was \emph{that}? Is this text trying to scare me or something? At the very least, it is making this page look a mess\dots
\vfill
\Large

This is some more non-frightening text. Friendly, approachable and keen to assist you whatever your needs.
\shadowoffsetx{-10pt}%
\shadowoffsety{-15pt}%
\shadowtext{%
  \shadowcolor{red!60!black}%
  \shadowoffsetx{3pt}%
  \shadowoffsety{5pt}%
  \shadowtext{\shadowtext{\shadowtext{\ECFTeenSpirit Be Afraid\dots Be Veeerrryyy Afraid\dots}}}}
\vfill

\LARGE\noindent This text is just minding its own business, doing no harm to anybody\dots
\begin{rotate}{45}%
    \shadowtext{\ECFWebster Somethin' woz 'ere}
\end{rotate}
said somebody. `Go figure,' said Pooh.
\vfill

\noindent Harmless text for armless times\dots \shadowtext{\Huge\ECFSkeetch SCARY Are you scared yet?}
\vfill

\shadowoffsetx{7.5pt}%
\noindent\Large \shadowoffsety{10pt}%
  \shadowtext{%
    \shadowoffsetx{-10pt}%
    \shadowoffsety{-15pt}%
    \shadowtext{%
      \shadowoffset{3pt}%
        \shadowtext{\ECFTallPaul Maybe this is more SCARY\dots SCARIER\dots?}}} Perhaps, or perhaps not so much?
\vfill

\noindent\Huge Now for some decidedly ordinary text\dots
\shadowtext{%
  \shadowoffsetx{-4pt}%
  \shadowoffsety{-2pt}%
  \shadowcolor{blue!40!black}%
  \shadowtext{\ECFPookie SCARY!!! Or just WEIRD?}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) implementation that *underlays* the "scary replication" using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbeshi), thus preserving the black overlaid text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,atbegshi}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcounter{wordcount}
\newcommand{\scarymacro}[2][10]{%
  \stepcounter{wordcount}%
  \tikz[remember picture, baseline, inner sep = 0pt] \node[anchor = base] (scary\thewordcount) {#2};%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\AtBeginShipout{\noexpand\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{
    \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \noexpand\foreach \noexpand\x in {1,...,#1}{%
        \noexpand\pgfmathparse{rand}\noexpand\edef\noexpand\xdir{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}% X-direction
        \noexpand\pgfmathparse{rand}\noexpand\edef\noexpand\ydir{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}% Y-direction
        \noexpand\pgfmathparse{100*(0.1+rnd*0.5)}\noexpand\edef\noexpand\scaryshade{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}% Shade
        \noexpand\pgfmathparse{0.5+rnd*0.5}\noexpand\edef\noexpand\scaryscale{\noexpand\pgfmathresult}% Scale
        \noexpand\node[color = red!\noexpand\scaryshade, scale = \noexpand\scaryscale]
          at ($(scary\thewordcount)+\noexpand\xdir*(1cm,0)+\noexpand\ydir*(0,1cm)$) {#2};}
    \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}
  }}}\x%
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis rhoncus cursus 
mi in pretium. Duis faucibus, leo sit amet hendrerit tempor, urna risus elementum 
leo, in tempus metus justo id nisl. Morbi adipiscing sapien venenatis est rutrum 
\scarymacro{scary} egestas. Phasellus commodo odio diam. Aenean a euismod diam. 
Maecenas lacinia tincidunt dolor nec posuere. Praesent accumsan consectetur luctus. 
Maecenas ac lorem at elit egestas scelerisque. Quisque tristique ligula sed nulla 
scelerisque, ut porta dolor faucibus. Sed et dui ac justo ultrices molestie. Sed 
tempus vitae dolor in sodales. Cras molestie elementum turpis in pharetra. Nullam 
turpis metus, iaculis nec \scarymacro[4]{scary} consectetur quis, adipiscing eleifend 
massa. Quisque blandit nisl id nisl fringilla commodo. Phasellus non faucibus 
tellus. Morbi non justo mauris.
\end{document}
```

...a close-up something scary:

[image]

The scary text is replicated 10 times by default when using `\scarymacro{<stuff>}`, but an optional argument can also be used to adjust the number of replications. Replication is printed in colour ranging from `red!10` to `red!60`, scaled between 50% and 100%, and randomly placed within a 1cm x 1cm proximity of `<stuff>`.

Comment: I really like the ghostly effect of this.