# Contour line around Truetype font in chapterstyle

Tags: fonts, xetex, truetype

I am sorry if this is already covered, but all the tips I've found seemed very hard to implement. You'll need the [Mikodacs](http://www.glukfonts.pl/font.php?font=Mikodacs) font in `FONTDIR`.

```
\documentclass[book,dvipsnames]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily{\archivo}[Path=/FONTDIR/]{Mikodacs.ttf}
\makechapterstyle{lucknerto}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-2\onelineskip}%
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{2\onelineskip}%
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}%
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\large\sffamily\bfseries}%
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}%
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\centering\archivo\color{White}\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
}
\chapterstyle{lucknerto}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Foobar}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

I am looking for something like this:

[image: outlined a]

I hope you can help!

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? What tips did you find?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125578/outline-text-using-truetype-fonts

Comment: @cfr I left them out as not to clutter my question.

Comment: @DanieEls I just tried the `shadowfy` macro from the first question, but can't get it to work with `chapterstyle`.

Comment: Maybe the `contour` package with the `outline` option, black contour color and white text color, would work?

Comment: @lblb, how would I get that to work with `chapterstyle`? I tried `\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\centering\archivo\color{Red}\contour{blue}\fontsize{23}{27.6}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}` but it won't compile.

Comment: But giving people access to what you found might help somebody find a solution, even if you couldn't make it work in your case.

Comment: @cfr: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25221/outlined-characters

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/how-to-change-color-of-edge-of-characters

Comment: You could probably use the approach with PDF literals. That should work, I think, with XeLaTeX if you choose the appropriate options. I'm not sure about this, mind, but it looks as if it should. But it will make things quite format/engine dependent., I believe.

Comment: @cfr I tried that, but have no idea how PDF literals work.

Comment: I *think* some implementation of this might work ...
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108881/32679

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your MWE to compile, even after having commented out the font-specific commands, so I minimised it further:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{0.01em}

\newcommand\contourchap[1]{\chapter*{\color{white}\contour{black}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\contourchap{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

The reason your approach with `\contour` in the comments doesn't compile is that `\contour` requires two arguments, the latter holds the content that gets the contour applied. You can't use such a command in `\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{...}`, because only switches are allowed there that are executed before printing the chapter title. Because of this, my MWE defines a new chapter command where the title is put *inside* the `\contour` command.

Comment: Hmm. This works in itself, but it fails when I add it to my document. With `xelatex` I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=16999999]` (after fiddling with memory settings) and with `lualatex` I get ` 830 words of node memory still in use:
   7 hlist, 1 vlist, 4 rule, 3 glue, 1 kern, 1 penalty, 1 glyph, 8 attribute, 14
9 glue_spec, 8 attribute_list, 2 if_stack, 1 write, 1 dir, 1 pdf_colorstack node
s
   avail lists: 1:3,2:261,3:35,4:292,5:64,6:301,7:14,8:1,9:123,10:44,11:1
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` after removing the `archivo` font.

Comment: Maybe `contour` is only compatible with `pdflatex`, I can't check now.