# Boldness of Any Fonts in Latex

Tags: bold

Of course we have `\textbf{}` to make a font (esp. English fonts) BOLD. I am interested in making a word BOLDER. I am aware of `\huge`, `\large` etc. But is there a way to make a word BOLDER, much more Bolder etc?

Comment: `\fontsize{66}{42}\selectfont}` (for example)? but this change size of font. don't mix font size with its shapes and series.

Comment: Perhaps a variant on Approach 2 at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295243/have-latex-document-slowly-transform-fade-from-one-font-into-another/331002#331002, using a pdfliteral approach.

Comment: Are you forced to use Computer Modern fonts, or are you free to use any font that's on your system?

Comment: @Mico I am not sure about that. I am using TexStudio in Win7 62bit though.

Comment: @Panha - The frontend (TeXstudio) and the operating system (Win7) should not really affect the decision regarding the fonts you use.