# Stacking 3 font weights

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I would like to write a presentation title in the following manner:

[image]

The 3 font weights appear to be stacked one on top of the other. Is this possible to manage with Tikz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER** (including actual 3-weight font)

This revision actually simplifies things a bit, as I don't have to do pdfliteral tricks to change the font weight, but actually use a font (OpenSans) that has 3 font weights.

The new trick here was setting each font weight with letter spacing equivalent to the bold-weight spacing, for which I created the macro `\boldwidth{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,trimclip}
\setstackgap{L}{0pt}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\newcommand\boldwidth[1]{\boldwidthaux#1\relax}
\def\boldwidthaux#1#2\relax{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\fontseries{b}\selectfont#1}%
  \makebox[\wd0][c]{#1}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\boldwidthaux#2\relax\fi%
}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black!80}
\sffamily

\fontseries{l}\selectfont
\color{black!70}\savestack\light{\kern1pt\boldwidth{JUNCTION}}
\color{black}\savestack\lightA{LIGHT}

\fontseries{m}\selectfont
\color{black!50}\savestack\regular{\kern.1pt\rotatebox{3.5}{\clipbox{-1pt -1pt 0pt 4pt}{%
                                   \rotatebox{-3.5}{\boldwidth{JUNCTION}}}}\kern-.1pt}
\color{black}\savestack\regularA{REGULAR}

\fontseries{b}\selectfont
\color{black!30}\savestack\heavy{\clipbox{-1pt -1pt 0pt 5pt}{\boldwidth{JUNCTION}}}
\color{black}\savestack\heavyA{BOLD}

\stackunder[0pt]{\Longunderstack{\light\\\regular\\\heavy}}{%
  \scalebox{.15}{\lightA\qquad\regularA\qquad\heavyA}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Based on a simplified version of my part 2 answer at [Have LaTeX document slowly transform/fade from one font into another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295243/have-latex-document-slowly-transform-fade-from-one-font-into-another/331002#331002), which employs pdfliteral magic provided by Malipivo at [TikZ: halo around text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/169549#169549).  That "stuff" allows me to set the color and thickness of the text, using pdf literal code.  I threw away the part of those answers that dealt with automatically varying the transformation as a function of text length.

NOTE: if I had a font that could give me three separate weights directly, I would not need this pdfliteral stuff at all.  Maybe someone could suggest a font.

Once I have the variable thickness/color texts, I create three versions in three different colors/weights, and then `\trimclip` them (with rotation as needed), and overlay them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine,trimclip}
%%%
\makeatletter
%%% MALIPIVO's PDF SPECIAL TO CHANGE FONT OUTLINE THICKNESS/COLOR
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/169549#169549
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\bordercolor{black}
\fillcolor{black}
%%% BRUNO's \slantbox
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63179/shear-transform-a-box/63188#63188
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.2]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
%%%
\setstackgap{L}{0pt}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}
\sffamily

\savestack\light{%
  \def\thickness{0.0}%
  \fillcolor{black!60}%
  \bordercolor{black!60}%
  \outline{JUNCTION}%
}

\savestack\medium{%
  \def\thickness{0.4}%
  \fillcolor{black!40}%
  \bordercolor{black!40}%
  \rotatebox{3}{\clipbox{0pt -1pt 0pt 4pt}{\rotatebox{-3}{\outline{JUNCTION}}}}%
}

\savestack\heavy{%
  \def\thickness{0.8}%
  \fillcolor{black!20}%
  \bordercolor{black!20}%
  \clipbox{0pt -1pt 0pt 5pt}{\outline{JUNCTION}}%
}

\Longunderstack{\light\\\medium\\\heavy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The font from the image (completely free) can be found here: https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/junction

Comment: @jrojasqu I have revised the answer to use OpenSans, which has 3 font weights and is accessible via pdflatex.  You should be able to adapt it to your font, if you use xelatex and sprinkle the answer with the proper xelatex incantations for changing the font weight.

Answer (score 3):

I still have a problem with letter alignment but this is an initial solution with `TikZ` and `microtype`. As I don't know how to use `microtype` or even don't know if it's the way to solve the problem, so feel free to change it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]

\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
    fill=black!80, font=\fontseries{l}\selectfont, text=black!70] (A) {\textls[50]{JUNCTION}};

\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift= -1pt]A.west)|-(A.south east)--([yshift= 4pt]A.east)--cycle;
\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
    fill=none, font=\fontseries{m}\selectfont, text=black!50, anchor=south] (B) at (A.south) {\textls[25]{JUNCTION}};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\clip ([yshift= -2pt]A.west)|-(A.south east)--([yshift= 1pt]A.east)--cycle;
\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
    fill=none, font=\fontseries{b}\selectfont, text=black!30, anchor=south] (C) at (A.south) {JUNCTION};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good. I vote your question. Hi.