# List of all available parameters of \boxgs{arg1}{arg2} of "pdf-trans" package

Tags: box, transformation

An interesting box transformation I have found on the following page:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169549/26458
is `pdf-trans` package. It seems there is no manual available. Only example is provided. However, I could not find even an example of `boxgs{arg1}{arg2}`. Could anybody explain the usage of the command? Especially the arguments spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\boxgs` is defined via

```
% box painted according to graphic state parameters (ie. on layer).

\def\boxgs#1#2{%
 \hbox\transboxdef
  \pdfliteral{q #1}%
  \savebp\trans:def\wd\transbox
  \box\transbox
  \pdfliteral{#2 Q 1 0 0 1 \trans:def\space 0 cm}%
 \transboxend}
```

So this is a lower level macro than the ones in the example file for standardard transformations such as rotate and scale etc.

The above definition uses other internal helper macros of the package but hopefully the basic intention is clear it sets a (following) box but preceded by the literal PDF in `#1` and followed by the PDF in `#2` together with some housekeeping PDF that is saving and restoring the state.

Hence the example that you link to

```
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr 0.3 w 0.47 0.6157 0.38 RG 1 0 0 rg }{}%
  \copy\qbox
```

is showing the contents of `\qrbox` transformed by the PDF operators `Q q 2 Tr 0.3 w 0.47 0.6157 0.38 RG 1 0 0 rg` (which do a translation and set some colours)

Comment: Where can we find the detail of `PDF operators`? Could you indicate the documentation?

Comment: @SayOL The PDF manual is freely available. eg https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

Comment: It is such a useful guide! Thank for the quick reply :)