# MiKTeX command similar to LaTeX?

Tags: macros, packages

I often use `\LaTeX` command but now looking for a command that produces the similar output for MiKTeX. Does it exist?

Answer (score 10):

The `hologo` package contains a MiKTeX logo:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{hologo}

\begin{document}
\hologo{MiKTeX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Using my related answer I posted just 10 minutes ago, [Blackboard bold greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562884/blackboard-bold-greek-letters/562926#562926), this will work only in pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\bordercolor[1]{\colsplit{1}{#1}}
\newcommand\fillcolor[1]{\colsplit{0}{#1}}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{\mydelim #1\mydelim}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \bbthickness\space w \fillcol\space \bordercol\space}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\mathbb[1]{\def\mydelim{$}\outline{#1}}
\newcommand\textbb[1]{\def\mydelim{}\outline{#1}}
\newcommand\colsplit[2]{\colorlet{tmpcolor}{#2}\edef\tmp{\usecolor{tmpcolor}}%
  \def\tmpB{}\expandafter\colsplithelp\tmp\relax%
  \ifnum0=#1\relax\edef\fillcol{\tmpB}\else\edef\bordercol{\tmpC}\fi}
\def\colsplithelp#1#2 #3\relax{%
  \edef\tmpB{\tmpB#1#2 }%
  \ifnum `#1>`9\relax\def\tmpC{#3}\else\colsplithelp#3\relax\fi
}
\newcommand\MiKTEX{\textbf{\rmfamily%
  \bordercolor{black}\newcommand\bbthickness{.15}\fillcolor{blue!50}%
  \textbb{M\kern-.8pti\kern-.8ptK\kern-.95ptT\kern-.9pt
  \raisebox{-.53ex}{E}\kern-.75ptX}}}
\begin{document}
Here is \MiKTEX{} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the website image for comparison

[image]

If you just want something simple that has no color, no outlines, and works on any engine, there is this adaptation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\MiKTEX{\textbf{\rmfamily%
  M\kern-.85pti\kern-.8ptK\kern-1.3ptT\kern-1.2pt
  \raisebox{-.51ex}{E}\kern-.77ptX}}
\begin{document}
Here is \MiKTEX{} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]