# Double Greek letters ("blackboard")

Tags: greek, math-fonts

Good day!

Does anybody know how to define double Greek letters in the text? There is an implementation using `\usepackage{mathbbol}`, but this gives an "ugly" variant of writing. :-)
I wish that the result would be closer to the following.

[image]

Or is it the same as `mtpro2`. For myself I use the `ConcreteMath` font style. Naturally, it also requires a double characterization of the `\Gamma` `\Delta` and `\Lambda`.

Comment: tex can not do this itself you need to reference a suitable font. what font did you use for your image above?

Comment: Look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562884/blackboard-bold-greek-letters