# pgfplot - How to stop contour lines from crossing contour labels?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transparency

I've been looking into the package manual (https://tools.ietf.org/doc/texlive-doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) but couldn't find a proper solution. I have a surf plot on top of which I place an additional contour plot via

`\addplot[contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab, contour/labels=true, contour/label distance=80pt, dashed, line width=1.0pt, contour/draw color=white] table[row sep=crcr] {...}`

Now, my goal is to make the contour numbers white and the contour labels transparent so they match the surf plot in the back. So I use something like:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    contour/every contour label/.style={
    nodes={text=white, opacity=1},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,}}
```

However, this clearly leads to the actual contour lines crossing the numbers (as shown by the picture below). Is there any compact solution to this issue which leaves the node transparent but still blocks the contour line from crossing the number? So far, I have only found the 'place on top' workaround, which I dislike.

Bonus question: Is there any option to only have 1 label per contour line? With the frequently recommended high distance option (distance=10000pt) the labels all get pushed outside the frame in my case.

A minimal code example which highlights the issue is given below

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
    contour/every contour label/.style={
    nodes={text=white, opacity=1},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0,
xmax=10,
ymin=0,
ymax=10]
\addplot[%
surf,
shader=faceted interp, faceted color=black, colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.2422,0.1504,0.6603); rgb(1pt)=(0.2444,0.1534,0.6728); rgb(2pt)=(0.2464,0.1569,0.6847); rgb(3pt)=(0.2484,0.1607,0.6961); rgb(4pt)=(0.2503,0.1648,0.7071); rgb(5pt)=(0.2522,0.1689,0.7179); rgb(6pt)=(0.254,0.1732,0.7286); rgb(7pt)=(0.2558,0.1773,0.7393); rgb(8pt)=(0.2576,0.1814,0.7501); rgb(9pt)=(0.2594,0.1854,0.761); rgb(11pt)=(0.2628,0.1932,0.7828); rgb(12pt)=(0.2645,0.1972,0.7937); rgb(13pt)=(0.2661,0.2011,0.8043); rgb(14pt)=(0.2676,0.2052,0.8148); rgb(15pt)=(0.2691,0.2094,0.8249); rgb(16pt)=(0.2704,0.2138,0.8346); rgb(17pt)=(0.2717,0.2184,0.8439); rgb(18pt)=(0.2729,0.2231,0.8528); rgb(19pt)=(0.274,0.228,0.8612); rgb(20pt)=(0.2749,0.233,0.8692); rgb(21pt)=(0.2758,0.2382,0.8767); rgb(22pt)=(0.2766,0.2435,0.884); rgb(23pt)=(0.2774,0.2489,0.8908); rgb(24pt)=(0.2781,0.2543,0.8973); rgb(25pt)=(0.2788,0.2598,0.9035); rgb(26pt)=(0.2794,0.2653,0.9094); rgb(27pt)=(0.2798,0.2708,0.915); rgb(28pt)=(0.2802,0.2764,0.9204); rgb(29pt)=(0.2806,0.2819,0.9255); rgb(30pt)=(0.2809,0.2875,0.9305); rgb(31pt)=(0.2811,0.293,0.9352); rgb(32pt)=(0.2813,0.2985,0.9397); rgb(33pt)=(0.2814,0.304,0.9441); rgb(34pt)=(0.2814,0.3095,0.9483); rgb(35pt)=(0.2813,0.315,0.9524); rgb(36pt)=(0.2811,0.3204,0.9563); rgb(37pt)=(0.2809,0.3259,0.96); rgb(38pt)=(0.2807,0.3313,0.9636); rgb(39pt)=(0.2803,0.3367,0.967); rgb(40pt)=(0.2798,0.3421,0.9702); rgb(41pt)=(0.2791,0.3475,0.9733); rgb(42pt)=(0.2784,0.3529,0.9763); rgb(43pt)=(0.2776,0.3583,0.9791); rgb(44pt)=(0.2766,0.3638,0.9817); rgb(45pt)=(0.2754,0.3693,0.984); rgb(46pt)=(0.2741,0.3748,0.9862); rgb(47pt)=(0.2726,0.3804,0.9881); rgb(48pt)=(0.271,0.386,0.9898); rgb(49pt)=(0.2691,0.3916,0.9912); rgb(50pt)=(0.267,0.3973,0.9924); rgb(51pt)=(0.2647,0.403,0.9935); rgb(52pt)=(0.2621,0.4088,0.9946); rgb(53pt)=(0.2591,0.4145,0.9955); rgb(54pt)=(0.2556,0.4203,0.9965); rgb(55pt)=(0.2517,0.4261,0.9974); rgb(56pt)=(0.2473,0.4319,0.9983); rgb(57pt)=(0.2424,0.4378,0.9991); rgb(58pt)=(0.2369,0.4437,0.9996); rgb(59pt)=(0.2311,0.4497,0.9995); rgb(60pt)=(0.225,0.4559,0.9985); rgb(61pt)=(0.2189,0.462,0.9968); rgb(62pt)=(0.2128,0.4682,0.9948); rgb(63pt)=(0.2066,0.4743,0.9926); rgb(64pt)=(0.2006,0.4803,0.9906); rgb(65pt)=(0.195,0.4861,0.9887); rgb(66pt)=(0.1903,0.4919,0.9867); rgb(67pt)=(0.1869,0.4975,0.9844); rgb(68pt)=(0.1847,0.503,0.9819); rgb(69pt)=(0.1831,0.5084,0.9793); rgb(70pt)=(0.1818,0.5138,0.9766); rgb(71pt)=(0.1806,0.5191,0.9738); rgb(72pt)=(0.1795,0.5244,0.9709); rgb(73pt)=(0.1785,0.5296,0.9677); rgb(74pt)=(0.1778,0.5349,0.9641); rgb(75pt)=(0.1773,0.5401,0.9602); rgb(76pt)=(0.1768,0.5452,0.956); rgb(77pt)=(0.1764,0.5504,0.9516); rgb(78pt)=(0.1755,0.5554,0.9473); rgb(79pt)=(0.174,0.5605,0.9432); rgb(80pt)=(0.1716,0.5655,0.9393); rgb(81pt)=(0.1686,0.5705,0.9357); rgb(82pt)=(0.1649,0.5755,0.9323); rgb(83pt)=(0.161,0.5805,0.9289); rgb(84pt)=(0.1573,0.5854,0.9254); rgb(85pt)=(0.154,0.5902,0.9218); rgb(86pt)=(0.1513,0.595,0.9182); rgb(87pt)=(0.1492,0.5997,0.9147); rgb(88pt)=(0.1475,0.6043,0.9113); rgb(89pt)=(0.1461,0.6089,0.908); rgb(90pt)=(0.1446,0.6135,0.905); rgb(91pt)=(0.1429,0.618,0.9022); rgb(92pt)=(0.1408,0.6226,0.8998); rgb(93pt)=(0.1383,0.6272,0.8975); rgb(94pt)=(0.1354,0.6317,0.8953); rgb(95pt)=(0.1321,0.6363,0.8932); rgb(96pt)=(0.1288,0.6408,0.891); rgb(97pt)=(0.1253,0.6453,0.8887); rgb(98pt)=(0.1219,0.6497,0.8862); rgb(99pt)=(0.1185,0.6541,0.8834); rgb(100pt)=(0.1152,0.6584,0.8804); rgb(101pt)=(0.1119,0.6627,0.877); rgb(102pt)=(0.1085,0.6669,0.8734); rgb(103pt)=(0.1048,0.671,0.8695); rgb(104pt)=(0.1009,0.675,0.8653); rgb(105pt)=(0.0964,0.6789,0.8609); rgb(106pt)=(0.0914,0.6828,0.8562); rgb(107pt)=(0.0855,0.6865,0.8513); rgb(108pt)=(0.0789,0.6902,0.8462); rgb(109pt)=(0.0713,0.6938,0.8409); rgb(110pt)=(0.0628,0.6972,0.8355); rgb(111pt)=(0.0535,0.7006,0.8299); rgb(112pt)=(0.0433,0.7039,0.8242); rgb(113pt)=(0.0328,0.7071,0.8183); rgb(114pt)=(0.0234,0.7103,0.8124); rgb(115pt)=(0.0155,0.7133,0.8064); rgb(116pt)=(0.0091,0.7163,0.8003); rgb(117pt)=(0.0046,0.7192,0.7941); rgb(118pt)=(0.0019,0.722,0.7878); rgb(119pt)=(0.0009,0.7248,0.7815); rgb(120pt)=(0.0018,0.7275,0.7752); rgb(121pt)=(0.0046,0.7301,0.7688); rgb(122pt)=(0.0094,0.7327,0.7623); rgb(123pt)=(0.0162,0.7352,0.7558); rgb(124pt)=(0.0253,0.7376,0.7492); rgb(125pt)=(0.0369,0.74,0.7426); rgb(126pt)=(0.0504,0.7423,0.7359); rgb(127pt)=(0.0638,0.7446,0.7292); rgb(128pt)=(0.077,0.7468,0.7224); rgb(129pt)=(0.0899,0.7489,0.7156); rgb(130pt)=(0.1023,0.751,0.7088); rgb(131pt)=(0.1141,0.7531,0.7019); rgb(132pt)=(0.1252,0.7552,0.695); rgb(133pt)=(0.1354,0.7572,0.6881); rgb(134pt)=(0.1448,0.7593,0.6812); rgb(135pt)=(0.1532,0.7614,0.6741); rgb(136pt)=(0.1609,0.7635,0.6671); rgb(137pt)=(0.1678,0.7656,0.6599); rgb(138pt)=(0.1741,0.7678,0.6527); rgb(139pt)=(0.1799,0.7699,0.6454); rgb(140pt)=(0.1853,0.7721,0.6379); rgb(141pt)=(0.1905,0.7743,0.6303); rgb(142pt)=(0.1954,0.7765,0.6225); rgb(143pt)=(0.2003,0.7787,0.6146); rgb(144pt)=(0.2061,0.7808,0.6065); rgb(145pt)=(0.2118,0.7828,0.5983); rgb(146pt)=(0.2178,0.7849,0.5899); rgb(147pt)=(0.2244,0.7869,0.5813); rgb(148pt)=(0.2318,0.7887,0.5725); rgb(149pt)=(0.2401,0.7905,0.5636); rgb(150pt)=(0.2491,0.7922,0.5546); rgb(151pt)=(0.2589,0.7937,0.5454); rgb(152pt)=(0.2695,0.7951,0.536); rgb(153pt)=(0.2809,0.7964,0.5266); rgb(154pt)=(0.2929,0.7975,0.517); rgb(155pt)=(0.3052,0.7985,0.5074); rgb(156pt)=(0.3176,0.7994,0.4975); rgb(157pt)=(0.3301,0.8002,0.4876); rgb(158pt)=(0.3424,0.8009,0.4774); rgb(159pt)=(0.3548,0.8016,0.4669); rgb(160pt)=(0.3671,0.8021,0.4563); rgb(161pt)=(0.3795,0.8026,0.4454); rgb(162pt)=(0.3921,0.8029,0.4344); rgb(163pt)=(0.405,0.8031,0.4233); rgb(164pt)=(0.4184,0.803,0.4122); rgb(165pt)=(0.4322,0.8028,0.4013); rgb(166pt)=(0.4463,0.8024,0.3904); rgb(167pt)=(0.4608,0.8018,0.3797); rgb(168pt)=(0.4753,0.8011,0.3691); rgb(169pt)=(0.4899,0.8002,0.3586); rgb(170pt)=(0.5044,0.7993,0.348); rgb(171pt)=(0.5187,0.7982,0.3374); rgb(172pt)=(0.5329,0.797,0.3267); rgb(173pt)=(0.547,0.7957,0.3159); rgb(175pt)=(0.5748,0.7929,0.2941); rgb(176pt)=(0.5886,0.7913,0.2833); rgb(177pt)=(0.6024,0.7896,0.2726); rgb(178pt)=(0.6161,0.7878,0.2622); rgb(179pt)=(0.6297,0.7859,0.2521); rgb(180pt)=(0.6433,0.7839,0.2423); rgb(181pt)=(0.6567,0.7818,0.2329); rgb(182pt)=(0.6701,0.7796,0.2239); rgb(183pt)=(0.6833,0.7773,0.2155); rgb(184pt)=(0.6963,0.775,0.2075); rgb(185pt)=(0.7091,0.7727,0.1998); rgb(186pt)=(0.7218,0.7703,0.1924); rgb(187pt)=(0.7344,0.7679,0.1852); rgb(188pt)=(0.7468,0.7654,0.1782); rgb(189pt)=(0.759,0.7629,0.1717); rgb(190pt)=(0.771,0.7604,0.1658); rgb(191pt)=(0.7829,0.7579,0.1608); rgb(192pt)=(0.7945,0.7554,0.157); rgb(193pt)=(0.806,0.7529,0.1546); rgb(194pt)=(0.8172,0.7505,0.1535); rgb(195pt)=(0.8281,0.7481,0.1536); rgb(196pt)=(0.8389,0.7457,0.1546); rgb(197pt)=(0.8495,0.7435,0.1564); rgb(198pt)=(0.86,0.7413,0.1587); rgb(199pt)=(0.8703,0.7392,0.1615); rgb(200pt)=(0.8804,0.7372,0.165); rgb(201pt)=(0.8903,0.7353,0.1695); rgb(202pt)=(0.9,0.7336,0.1749); rgb(203pt)=(0.9093,0.7321,0.1815); rgb(204pt)=(0.9184,0.7308,0.189); rgb(205pt)=(0.9272,0.7298,0.1973); rgb(206pt)=(0.9357,0.729,0.2061); rgb(207pt)=(0.944,0.7285,0.2151); rgb(208pt)=(0.9523,0.7284,0.2237); rgb(209pt)=(0.9606,0.7285,0.2312); rgb(210pt)=(0.9689,0.7292,0.2373); rgb(211pt)=(0.977,0.7304,0.2418); rgb(212pt)=(0.9842,0.733,0.2446); rgb(213pt)=(0.99,0.7365,0.2429); rgb(214pt)=(0.9946,0.7407,0.2394); rgb(215pt)=(0.9966,0.7458,0.2351); rgb(216pt)=(0.9971,0.7513,0.2309); rgb(217pt)=(0.9972,0.7569,0.2267); rgb(218pt)=(0.9971,0.7626,0.2224); rgb(219pt)=(0.9969,0.7683,0.2181); rgb(220pt)=(0.9966,0.774,0.2138); rgb(221pt)=(0.9962,0.7798,0.2095); rgb(222pt)=(0.9957,0.7856,0.2053); rgb(223pt)=(0.9949,0.7915,0.2012); rgb(224pt)=(0.9938,0.7974,0.1974); rgb(225pt)=(0.9923,0.8034,0.1939); rgb(226pt)=(0.9906,0.8095,0.1906); rgb(227pt)=(0.9885,0.8156,0.1875); rgb(228pt)=(0.9861,0.8218,0.1846); rgb(229pt)=(0.9835,0.828,0.1817); rgb(230pt)=(0.9807,0.8342,0.1787); rgb(231pt)=(0.9778,0.8404,0.1757); rgb(232pt)=(0.9748,0.8467,0.1726); rgb(233pt)=(0.972,0.8529,0.1695); rgb(234pt)=(0.9694,0.8591,0.1665); rgb(235pt)=(0.9671,0.8654,0.1636); rgb(236pt)=(0.9651,0.8716,0.1608); rgb(237pt)=(0.9634,0.8778,0.1582); rgb(238pt)=(0.9619,0.884,0.1557); rgb(239pt)=(0.9608,0.8902,0.1532); rgb(240pt)=(0.9601,0.8963,0.1507); rgb(241pt)=(0.9596,0.9023,0.148); rgb(242pt)=(0.9595,0.9084,0.145); rgb(243pt)=(0.9597,0.9143,0.1418); rgb(244pt)=(0.9601,0.9203,0.1382); rgb(245pt)=(0.9608,0.9262,0.1344); rgb(246pt)=(0.9618,0.932,0.1304); rgb(247pt)=(0.9629,0.9379,0.1261); rgb(248pt)=(0.9642,0.9437,0.1216); rgb(249pt)=(0.9657,0.9494,0.1168); rgb(250pt)=(0.9674,0.9552,0.1116); rgb(251pt)=(0.9692,0.9609,0.1061); rgb(252pt)=(0.9711,0.9667,0.1001); rgb(253pt)=(0.973,0.9724,0.0938); rgb(254pt)=(0.9749,0.9782,0.0872); rgb(255pt)=(0.9769,0.9839,0.0805)}, mesh/rows=3]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   c\\
1   1   0.13141548695608\\
1   5   1.39382994884043\\
1   10  0.706213422777802\\
5   1   1.16284681064975\\
5   5   -0.753687723707311\\
5   10  0.32192470229602\\
10  1   1.63570420209551\\
10  5   -0.647794522894829\\
10  10  0.673263302065595\\
};
\addplot[no marks, contour prepared, contour prepared format=matlab, contour/labels=true,dashed, line width=1.0pt, contour/draw color=white] table[row sep=crcr] {%
0.3 2\\
10  0\\
0 10\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: contour labels crossed by contour lines]

Comment: I think that if you want an answer to this question you need to provide a complete compilable code. Otherwise you expect others to write a code and play around until they reproduce your issue, and then fix it. This may or may not happen, I think the second possibility is more likely.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I now added a working minimal example which highlights the issue. I did not include one earlier as I had hoped that there would be some well known and integrated option to this issue.

Comment: Well, in this example a possible solution is to use `nodes={text=white, opacity=1,fill=blue!10},` but this only works for some uniform background.` labels over line` should also work. Well, with regards to the problem of a nonuniform background we are back at square one since the example does not have such a background.

Comment: Sorry in advance for possibly sounding rude, but at some point you have to decide whether you want a minimal example or the fully complex one. I explicitly told you that I just emulated the surf picture with a background color to reduce the required code - so, as you have already stated in your comment, the given solution is not viable. If I were to provide the full surf plot and you would just create a solution that manually replaces every single pixel of the surf plot for each label, then this would not be an effective or robust solution either that anyone on here would seriously recommend.

Comment: As I said, it was a trade-off to keep the code example as simple as possible while still completely conveying the point of the question. Which it indeed did, as shown by your answer. However, you were more interested in dissecting the question for arguments sake instead of just answering it.... That being said, I now edited the example to account for a non-linear background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
contour/label node code/.code={\stepcounter{n}; \node (p\then) {\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}; \coordinate (sw\then) at (p\then.south west); \coordinate (ne\then) at (p\then.north east);},
/pgfplots/contour/contour label style={nodes={text=white, fill=none, transform shape=false, inner sep=1pt, opacity=1}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
0 10 0.3
3 8 0.3
6 7 0.3
10 0 0.3
0 0 0.4
10 4.5 0.4
}\loadedtable
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10]
\addplot[patch, patch type=rectangle, shader=interp, point meta=explicit] coordinates {
(0,0) [0]
(0,10) [1] 
(10,10) [2]
(10,0) [3] 
};
\newcounter{n}
\setcounter{n}{0}
\addplot[contour prepared, opacity=0] table {\loadedtable};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,4} {\clip (sw#1) rectangle (ne#1) (0,10) rectangle (10,0);}
\addplot[contour prepared, thick, dashed, contour/draw color=white] table {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with multi colored background and contourlines]

Answer (score 2):

yeah, thanks for this link.
For me your code works perfectly and I have the same problem with the background fill. The idea is to fill with mapped colour. It works for me changing the `\pgfplotsset`:

```
\pgfplotsset{
        contour/every contour label/.style={
          nodes={text=black, fill=mapped color,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=1pt,#1},
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1}
        }
```

The only problem for this solution is that it seems that it takes only one color to fill and maybe with smarter fill as:
[TikZ: halo around text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text)
Maybe you obtain better solution.