# Can I make a greek letter extra-bold in math mode?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols)

I would like to distinguish between a vector of betas and the individual betas and I want to use **bold** symbol, rather than an error, to indicate the vector.

However, I see from [How can I get bold math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/1783) pointed out by @Werner that there is no difference between `\beta` and `\mathbf{beta}`.

However, even `\bm{beta}` could use a little fattening-up, in my opinion, and the `\hm` from the `bm` package. Can I make the beta's extra bold? My current solution is just to use "B" instead.

for comparison, here is the output of

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\beta \mathbf{\beta} \bm{\beta} \hm{\beta} \bm{\beta\mkern-11mu\beta}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your tests did you use `\bm` as you stated in your question or `\mathbf` as you showed in code and the image. `\mathbf` has no effect on `\beta` in the default setup.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=boldgreek

Comment: I think the following is a duplicate: [How can I get bold math symbols?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595/5764)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I used `\mathbf` in my tests. `\bm` definitely works, but I would like to know if I could make it "double-bold".

Comment: @Werner it does pretty much solve the issue, but I'd still like to know if I can make the `\bm{\beta}` even more bold. So I have revised the question to make the distinction.

Comment: @David does this help at all: [how-can-i-put-a-coloured-outline-around-fraction-lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/how-can-i-put-a-coloured-outline-around-fraction-lines)

Comment: How "bold" a given symbol looks is entirely dependent on the font. cm fonts are always fairly skinny, mathtime (for which bm was originally written) has two weights of bold bold and extra bold (called heavy with short command `\hm` in `bm.sty` but even without changing to commercial fonts just switching amongst the available font packages might do something you prefer, or there is always `\bm{\beta\mkern-10mu\beta}` but that is fairly horrible.

Comment: I used `mkern-11mu` in my example, not so horrible - I like double line notation when writing by hand at least - but you are right, I wouldn't want to publish that

Answer (score 7):

Use "poor man's bold" combined with `\bm`. Like this:`\pmb{\bm{\beta}}`. In math mode of course. This requires the `amsmath` package.